# Reuse the same thread

Tags: c, multithreading

I am writing a program for an assignment,which implements matrix multiplication between two given arrays,using threads.

I must give the number of threads i want to use as a command line argument and if the number of them is smaller than the number of lines of the first array,reuse some the same threads until the whole job is done.

I have managed to make it work but only using a thread for each row of the array.
For example if a have a 5x5 multiplication and use less than 5 threads i take a segmentation fault,which makes sense.

My question is:How can i reuse a thread after this thread has finished its job?
In the previous example i mean that if i want to use 2 threads for a 5x5 my program should work like this:

thread 1->line 1

thread 2->line 2

thread 2->line 3

thread 1->line 4

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several possibilities, but the main idea is that you must monitor threads to detect when they have finished their job, and have a way to know if there's still something left to do.

The first way that comes to mind is to have a dedicated thread to track all the running threads, and recycle them once they're finished. But in order to do that, you need a mechanism to let threads synchronize, which may be implemented using semaphores or mutex, or messages, but it could be cumbersome to code just for that purpose if you don't have a need for it already.

The second way is simply to ask them to recycle themselves, since they know when they are done. In many other languages, there's a mechanism called continuations, which let you exactly that, but since we're dealing with C, we need to do that by hand. Luckily, here the continuation is actually just one single task.

So the mechanism to call the continuation is actually just a function, which will first run the task to be executed by the thread, and then either:

- check a task list. This task list must be filled at setup time with all the work which need to be done by the tasks,
- add the thread to a queue of available threads, which must be checked again by some other thread and reassigned a new task,

Obviously, the first option would be easier, and in your case, you already know at setup time what has to be done, so your setup function could fill up a list of tasks and then launch as many threads as you want, and let them do the recycling themselves.

Here's a simple skeleton you could start with:

```
 typedef struct {
    /* task related data */
 } task_t;

 // basic list structure
 typedef struct {
   list_t *next;
   void *data; // here app specific data
 } list_t;

 list_t task_list; // your task list

 // a few operators to manipulate a list
 // implementation must use a mutex to avoid race conditions
 void list_push(list *l, void *data);
 void *list_pop(list *l);


 // thread function

 void do_task(task_t *task){
     while (task) {
       run_task(task); // that would be the matrix related function
       task = list_pop(&task_list);
 }

 // here a simple define for the number of threads
 // you might want to check the number of available cores instead

 #define MAX_THREAD_COUNT 4 

 int main() {

   pthread_t threads[MAX_THREAD_COUNT];

   setup_task_list();  // push all the work that must be done in the list
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
      pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, do_task, list_pop(&task_list));
   }

   // here wait for all the threads, or detach them

 }
```

This is a basic outline of what you could do, and should get you started.
There are several questions on SO dealing with C linked lists. The one here must be synchronized, should not block, and return `NULL` when empty.

Comment: Thanks for answering.I understood the 2 ways.The second seems easier for me but I will try to use a mutex as the assignment says.Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: In the second setup, you will have to use a mutex for the linked list anyway.

Comment: Ok fixed it by using one simple mutex for the row being calculated at each moment.My program works fine and prints the final result as expected when using any number of threads.But i have one last question.I use a print statement to check which thread is operating on the current row.This on 5x5 matrix example shows that only thread 1 is operating on all rows and only after some random runs i can see for one row that thread 2 operated on this.Is it logical?I assume that it happens because in a small matrix all operations are done very quicky and there is no job left for thread 2.Is it right?

Comment: that's a strong possibility. For very small tasks, the timeslice allocated for a thread by the system might be well enough to let it do all the work, before being rescheduled. You could try forcing the thread to relinquish CPU by using `pthread_yeld();` right after getting a new task to process (that would be either before  `run_task` or at the end of the `while` loop in my code).

Comment: Thank you again!I used pthread_yeld(),after the operation in the worker function of thread,and now everything seems to work as expected and all threads are used.Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget that in the real world, tasks would certainly be much more time/CPU consuming, and wouldn't necessitate a yeld for all threads to be effectively used.